# MySQL server stuck when use CONVERT_TZ

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-date

I have a table of Doctor like:

```
-----------------------------
| id |       open_at        |
-----------------------------
| 1  | 2020-03-13 10:50:03  |
| 2  | 2020-03-21 23:15:15  |
| 3  | 2020-04-11 14:23:11  |
-----------------------------
And more values like this
```

I apply this query which obviously works fine.

```
SELECT id, open_at FROM mydb.doctor;
```

However, when I apply `CONVERT_TZ`, the server hangs. This is how the query looks.

```
SELECT id, CONVERT_TZ(open_at, 'GMT', 'EST') AS 'open_time'
FROM mydb.doctor;
```

With this query, the server hangs, and the query keeps processing even for an hour.

Comment: Are the timezone tables loaded ? see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/convert_tz/

Comment: Yes it's loaded. I think, the server should give some response, at least. It's hanged, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UTC rather than GMT u can check this link for more information [convert GMT time to EST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151481/convert-gmt-time-to-est).Hoping it will help.